# Can Django admin user edit the base.html page from backend?

Tags: django, jinja2

I'd like to edit the background image of  in the base.html template. I was thinking of having a model and form, that way the user/admin can just upload new images to the background. The issue I think I'm having is referencing the base.html template directly since it's never called directly.

I was thinking of just pushing the style in line, or editing the CSS directly would be cool too. I just have only been able to toggle different CSS prewritten codes

I've tried having a base_view(request) but doesn't work
(base.html is never called, so I assume that's why and obviously the extended pages don't modify the base.html)

```
def base_view(request):
    context = {
        'post': BackgroundImage.objects.last()
    }
    return render(request, 'base.html', context)
```

So this is what I have:

models.py:

```
class BackgroundImageModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg", upload_to='background_pics')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 2000 or img.width > 2000:
            output_size = (2000, 2000)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

views.py:

```
class BackgroundImage(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = BackgroundImageModel
    fields = ['image']
```

base.html:

```
{% if background %}
          <body style="background:
          url({{ background.image.url }})
          repeat fixed center; 
          margin: 5rem 0 2rem 0;">
{% else %}
          <body style=" margin: 5rem 0 2rem 0;">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Please shoe you urls and highlight which one you want to show the base html

Comment: Not sure I understand, I'm trying to just be able to change the url to the background image on the base.html page. If there is a way to do it directly to the CSS file, I'm down to do that, but I'm just trying to do it to the base.html file with inline CSS atm

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the image as `post` in your `context` but you're using `background` in the html.

Try:

```
{% if background %}
      <body style="background:
      url({{ post.image.url }})
      repeat fixed center; 
      margin: 5rem 0 2rem 0;">
{% else %}
      <body style=" margin: 5rem 0 2rem 0;">
{% endif %}
```